# Set the property of object by its name in TypeScript without losing static typing

Tags: typescript

I have 2 JSX components

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    lastName: string;
}


<EditableString
            isEditing={() => this.getIsEditing(index)}
            getStoredValue={() => this.props.items[index].data.item.name}
            getEditingValue={() => this.editingRow && this.editingRow.name ? this.editingRow.name : ''}
            setValueForEditingRow={
                action((value: string) => {
                    if (this.editingRow) {
                        this.editingRow.name = value;
                    }
                })
            }
        />


<EditableString
            isEditing={() => this.getIsEditing(index)}
            getStoredValue={() => this.props.items[index].data.item.lastName}
            getEditingValue={() => this.editingRow && this.editingRow.lastName? this.editingRow.LastName: ''}
            setValueForEditingRow={
                action((value: string) => {
                    if (this.editingRow) {
                        this.editingRow.lastName = value;
                    }
                })
            }
        />
```

Can I write a universal function, that passes the property name as a parameter? In plain JS I can do something like

```
this.editingRow[propTitle] = value;
```

How can I do that in TS? If there is a way that I can narrow the prop titles down to the type or interface, it would be perfect. (In my case restrict them to be only `'name'` or `'lastName'`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the most nice and clean way but it works

```
public getEditableString = (index: number, editingRowProp: keyof IParentRow, offerViewProp: keyof IOfferView) => <td>
    <EditableString
        isEditing={() => this.getIsEditing(index)}
        getStoredValue={() => this.props.items[index].data.item[offerViewProp] as string}
        getEditingValue={() => this.editingRow && this.editingRow[editingRowProp] as string ? this.editingRow[editingRowProp] as string : ''}
        setValueForEditingRow={
            action((value: string) => {
                if (this.editingRow) {
                    this.editingRow[editingRowProp] = value;
                }
            })
        }
    />
</td>
```